# What Fresh Tomato settings to use to connect to modem with ip 192.168.1.1?

Tags: router, tomato

you’re my last straw. I bought a netgear nighthawk r7000 router and it worked fine out of the box (the genie switches to 10.0.0.1 because of an ip conflict with my modem). I flashed the firmware to fresh tomato. The connection to the router is fine(utp or WiFi) but I can’t reach past the router. (‘Connected, no internet’) I changed the router ip to 192.168.1.200 to avoid a conflict but that does not help. I’ve tried both the routers lan and wan utp ports to connect to the modem. Does anyone have a suggestion to tackle this problem? Thanks a million in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? We don't the type of modem you are dealing with, all information, like your operating system, might help. Have you visited the Netgear site https://community.netgear.com/t5/Nighthawk-WiFi-Routers/Nighthawk-R7000-IP-Assignment-Conflicts/td-p/1608122

Comment: If he flashed it with tomato then he wont find any help at a Netgear forum.  @OP Your modem output should be connected to the WAN port. In tomato, your configuration for the WAN port should be configured for DHCP(or words to that effect). This alone should allow it to connect to the internet under most circumstances. If this doesn't do the trick then we will most likely need more details from you to help.

Comment: Thanks! So I have to configure the router to receive an up from the modem? I’ll look if I will get it to work today.

Comment: I meant ‘ip’, not ‘up’

Comment: Update: it works! The trick seemed to be an IP change to 192.168.2.1. I guess it's because it's in another subnet than 192.168.1.1 (subnetmask 255.255.255.0)
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I had that 10.0.0.1 switch as well when I used stock netgear firmware

And A LOT of problems with tomato, as they seem to not have NAT (which is the 10.0.0.1 thing).

Now the solution as mentioned in the tiiiny comment of OP is this:

this *seems* to work, tested during the last 10 minutes

BASIC - NETWORK - LAN
switch IP address to 192.168.2.1
switch IP range to: 192.168.2.2 to 192.168.2.51

leave everything else identical

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this was very helpful